# Jump to next/previous non-commented non-whitespace line

Tags: visual-studio-code, navigation

I spend a lot of time editing config files that are mostly comments. Is there an easy way to move the cursor to the next/previous line that has non-commented text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By (Move By)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) to move the cursor based on a regex. If you bind it to a key you move very fast.